# I am facing HTTP2 protocol errror or ERR_Connection_closed when http2 request is with more than 45 cookies

Tags: http, load, protocols, load-balancing, f5

I am facing one Problem on the Production webshop.
When we are sending a request to Hybris Server then we are facing an issue(generally with POST request). This is not happening everytime but sometimes it happens when number of cookies is reaching to a level of 45. It does not look like a problem with header size as we are able to reproduce the issue with lets say 5000 bytes header size but it is not reproducible for header size 7000.
The one thing that we have noticed is that this happens for HTTP/2 protocol calls and not with HTTP/1.1 calls. If we disable HTTP/2 on F5 LTM then this issue is not reproduced.
To reproduce the issue on our end, we just increase the number of cookies to be send with the request but everytime it reaches to 45 count, it breaks.
Our Infra layer is F5 LTM and then Apache Web Servers and then Hybris Servers.

We confirmed that request is not reaching to Apache/Hybris Servers.

Any lead on this will be helpful.
Is there any configuration on Load Balancer level to limit number of cookies in the request or any other configuration around the same.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPJju.png)